# ¿Cómo se dice la expresión "screen name"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

La traducción literal de "screen name" – un nombre de usuario para un servicio en línea – es "nombre de pantalla".

¿Se utiliza eso comúnmente? ¿O se utiliza otra frase en su lugar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Español

Miguel propone dos buenas traducciones con "nombre de usuario" y "usuario" cuando "username" y "screen name" son sinónimos. Sin embargo, puede que en tu caso no lo sean. Esto sucede cuando una cosa es el nombre de usuario (username o ID), es decir, con el que inicias sesión y estás registrado en el sistema, y otra cosa es "screen name", el nombre en pantalla, es decir, un nombre del usuario que aparecerá en pantalla en vez de su nombre de usuario. Por ejemplo, cuando el usuario escribe un comentario, en vez de aparecer su "username" *jperez*, aparecería su "screen name", *Juan Pérez*. Aquí en StackExchange se llama "display name".

Si es tu caso, yo traduciría "screen name" como "nombre en pantalla", me suena haberlo visto así en algunos sitios.

---

### English

Miguel suggests two good translations "nombre de usuario" and "usuario" when "username" and "screen name" are synonyms . However, it might not be your case. This happens when one thing is the username or ID, that is, your login name and the one with you are signed in the system, and other thing is the screen name, that is, a user name that will appear on the screen instead of the *username*. For example, when the user posts a comment, instead of appearing his "username" *jperez*, we would see his "screen name", *Juan Pérez*. Here in StackExchange they call it "display name".

If this is your case, I would translate "screen name" as "nombre en pantalla", I think I saw it like this in some sites.

Comment: Why not **nombre artístico**? This is not Hollywood but this is the idea.

Answer (score 8):

## Español

*Nota: Esta respuesta supone que "screen name" y "username" son sinónimos.*

Las versiones en español de [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Especial:Entrar&returnto=Wikipedia%3APortada), [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/), y [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/) usan el término `nombre de usuario`, y creo que es la forma más común. [Wordpress.com en Español](http://es.wordpress.com/) usa la palabra inglés *username*. También he visto la palabra `usuario` usado en algunos contextos, pero es menos formal y no es tan común.

---

## English

*Note: This answer assumes that "screen name" and "username" are synonyms.*

The Spanish versions of [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Especial:Entrar&returnto=Wikipedia%3APortada), [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/), & [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/) use the term `nombre de usuario`, and I believe that's the most common form. [Wordpress.com in Spanish](http://es.wordpress.com/) just uses the English word *username*. I've also seen the word `usuario` used in some contexts, but this seems less formal and isn't quite as common.

I hope this helps! :)